# nth-of-type not working properly

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply a style to every other *.tile-half*, but I also have .tile-wide which I want to skip.

```
<div class="tile tile-half">...</div>
<div class="tile tile-half">...</div>
<div class="tile tile-wide">...</div>
<div class="tile tile-half">...</div>
<div class="tile tile-half">...</div>
```

And here is my css

```
.tile-half:nth-of-type(2n)
{
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

What appears to be happening is it is selecting every second child and then applying the style to it only if it is of the type. I want it to act as though the *.tile-wide* isn't even there.

Comment: Try .tile-half:nth-of-type(3n-1)
{
    margin-left: 2%;
}

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like this isn't possible as :nth-of-type only works on elements and not classes. So I just used

```
.tile-half + .tile-half
{
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```